# "List elements that take up more than one line are not permitted" error with complex IF statement

Tags: abap

I'm new to ABAP coding in APDs.  How would I write a statement like this in ABAP code?

```
if ((ls_source-VHMODEL == 'M1' OR ls_source-VHMODEL == 'M2') AND (ls_source-CREATE_DATE <= '2016-01-01' AND ls_source-CREATE_DATE >= '2014-01-01'))
{
// do stuff
}
else if ((ls_source-VHMODEL == 'H1' OR ls_source-VHMODEL == 'C3') AND (ls_source-CREATE_DATE <= '2015-01-01' AND ls_source-CREATE_DATE >= '2014-02-01'))
{
// do stuff
}
```

I tried this:

```
  if ( ( ls_source-VHMODEL EQ 'M1' OR ls_source-VHMODEL EQ 'M2')  AND
(ls_source-CREATE_DATE > '20120122' AND ls_source-CREATE_DATE < '20120922')).
    MOVE 'Segment 2' TO ls_target-SEGMENT.
  else.
    MOVE 'Other' TO ls_target-SEGMENT.
  endif.
```

But that gave me the error

> Syntax error: List elements that take up more than one line are not permitted.

Comment: I've read http://scn.sap.com/thread/1724117, but it doesn't give me example of how to perform an evaluation on more than 1 variable.  I read http://sapstack.com/abap/abap-if-statement and again, it doesn't give me example of how to perform an evaluation on more than 1 variable.  I tried `if ((ls_source-VHMODEL EQ 'M1' OR ls_source-VHMODEL EQ 'M2') AND (ls_source-CREATE_DATE <= '2016-01-01' AND ls_source-CREATE_DATE >= '2014-01-01')).` but I got `Syntax error: List elements that take up more than one line are not permitted.` even though everything was on one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (  ( ls_source-vhmodel eq 'M1' or ls_source-vhmodel eq 'M2' ) and
      ( ls_source-create_date le '20160101' and ls_source-create_date ge '20140101' )
   ).
* Do something
elseif (
          ( ls_source-vhmodel eq 'H1' or ls_source-vhmodel eq 'C3' ) and
          ( ls_source-create_date le '20150101' and ls_source-create_date ge '20140201' )
       ).
*Do something
endif.
```

Be aware of the parentheses how they are separated in the code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I get the error `Syntax error: List elements that take up more than one line are not permitted`

Comment: Is it possible that you post your code to check exactly what is wrong please?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it out. Well, in my case you can see in my code that the parentheses are separated by a space, the same in the beginning between the open parentheses and the variable. Try exactly this: if ( ( ls_source-VHMODEL EQ 'M1' OR ls_source-VHMODEL EQ 'M2')  AND
( ls_source-CREATE_DATE > '20120122' AND ls_source-CREATE_DATE < '20120922') ).
  MOVE 'Segment 2' TO ls_target-SEGMENT.
else.
  MOVE 'Other' TO ls_target-SEGMENT.
endif.

Answer (score 2):

Could you check that your parenthesis are preceded and followed by a space ?.

The ABAP compiler is notoriously sensible for such things, since parenthesis may mean somthing else (ie. offset in data).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is parentheses and also spacing before and after `(` and `)`.

This code compiles:

```
if ( ls_source-vhmodel eq 'M1' or ls_source-vhmodel eq 'M2' )  and
  ( ls_source-create_date > '20120122' and ls_source-create_date < '20120922' ).
  move 'Segment 2' to ls_target-segment.
else.
  move 'Other' to ls_target-segment.
endif.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't left a space between the parentheses.  Unlike other languages ABAP requires a space between the parentheses and the rest of the statement.

```
(ls_source-CREATE_DATE > '20120122' AND ls_source-CREATE_DATE < '20120922')).
^^^                                                                       ^^^
```